# How to replace a value in text file using powershell script

Tags: powershell

My file consists of following data (no header)

```
DEPOSIT ADD     123456789 (VALUE)(VARIABLE) NNNN    VALUEVARIABLE                                                   
DEPOSIT ADD     234567890 (VALUE)(P75)  NNNN    VALUEVARIABLE                                               
DEPOSIT ADD     345678901 (VALUE)(VARIABLE) NNNN    VALUEVARIABLE
```

This is a tab delimited text file.
There are total of 5 columns. (123456789 (VALUE)(VARIABLE) is a single value column)

My requirements are:

1. I need to fetch only the row which contains **P75** to update in the same file.
2. I have to replace the values in Col3,Col4 and in Col5 after fetching **P75** other rows should be unaffected.

from

```
DEPOSIT ADD     234567890 (VALUE)(P75)  NNNN    VALUEVARIABLE
```

to

```
DEPOSIT ADD     234567890 (VTG)(SPVTG)  TCM    VTGSPVTG
```

3. Only the records which contains P75 should be updated like this. The replace values are same for all selected records.

My script which I have written is

```
$original_file='C:\Path\20200721130155_copy.txt' -header Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,| Select Col3,Col4,Col5

(Get-Content $original_file) |ForEach-Object {

    if($_.Col3 -match '(VALUE)(P75)')
    {
    $_ -replace '(VALUE)(P75)', '(VTG)(SPVTG)' `
       -replace 'VALUEVARIABLE', 'VTGSPVTG' `
       -replace 'NNNN', 'TCM' `
    } 
    $_
    }| Set-Content $original_file+'_new.txt' -Force
```

I am getting output file with same content. The file is not getting updated.

Please advice.

Thanks

Comment: `-replace` alone replaces text just for the current call (doesn't save the changes). If you want the object to see the update then you must assign the change back to it -> `$_  = $_ -replace '\(VALUE\)\(P75\)', '(VTG)(SPVTG)'`

Comment: I tried updating like this   `{`
    `$_ = $_ -replace '\(VALUE\)\(P75\)', '(VTG)(SPVTG)' `
      ` -replace 'VALUEVARIABLE', 'VTGSPVTG' `
      ` -replace 'NNNN', 'TCM' `
   ` } ` it still is not updating the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
$newfile = "{0}_new.txt" -f $original_file
Get-Content $original_file | Foreach-Object {
    if ($_ -match '\(VALUE\)\(P75\)') {
        $_ -replace '\(VALUE\)\(P75\)','(VTG)(SPVTG)' -replace 'VALUEVARIABLE', 'VTGSPVTG' -replace 'NNNN', 'TCM'
    } else {
        $_
    }
} | Set-Content $newfile -Force
```

Since `-replace` uses regex, you must backslash escape special regex characters like `(` and `)`.

Since `$_` is the current line read from `Get-Content` without `-Raw`, you will need to output `$_` if you want to make no changes. If you do want to replace text, then `$_ -replace 'regex','text'` will output that line with the replaced text.

---

Alternatively, you can apply the same logic above in a `switch` statement, which is more efficient:

```
$newfile = "{0}_new.txt" -f $original_file
$(switch -regex -file $original_file {
    '\(VALUE\)\(P75\)' {
        $_ -replace '\(VALUE\)\(P75\)','(VTG)(SPVTG)' -replace 'VALUEVARIABLE', 'VTGSPVTG' -replace 'NNNN', 'TCM'
    }
    default { $_ }
}) | Set-Content $newfile -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `` Import-Csv -Delimiter "`t" `` to import the data of the original file.
Then loop over the items and change the values if Col3 matches the search text.

```
$original_file = 'C:\Path\20200721130155_copy.txt'
$out_file      = $original_file -replace '\.txt$', '_new.txt'

(Import-Csv -Path $original_file -Delimiter "`t" -Header 'Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4','Col5') | ForEach-Object {
    if( $_.Col3 -like '*(*)*(P75)') {
        $_.Col3 = $_.Col3 -replace '\([^)]+\)\(P75\)$', '(VTG)(SPVTG)'
        $_.Col4 = 'TCM'
        $_.Col5 = 'VTGSPVTG'
    } 
    # rejoin the fields and output the line
    $_.PsObject.Properties.Value -join "`t"
} | Set-Content -Path $out_file -Force
```

Output will be

```
DEPOSIT ADD 123456789 (VALUE)(VARIABLE) NNNN    VALUEVARIABLE
DEPOSIT ADD 234567890 (VTG)(SPVTG)  TCM VTGSPVTG
DEPOSIT ADD 345678901 (VALUE)(VARIABLE) NNNN    VALUEVARIABLE
```

Regex details for `-replace`:

```
\(        Match the character “(” literally
[^)]      Match any character that is NOT a “)”
   +      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\)        Match the character “)” literally
\(        Match the character “(” literally
P75       Match the characters “P75” literally
\)        Match the character “)” literally
$         Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
```