# How to replace a value in multiple text files and move the files using powershell script by looping

Tags: powershell

My files consists of following data (no header). Lets take 2 files

b1.txt

```
DEPOSIT ADD     123456789 (VALUE)(VARIABLE) NNNN    VALUEVARIABLE                                                   
DEPOSIT ADD     234567890 (VALUE)(P75)  NNNN    VALUEVARIABLE
```

b2.txt

```
DEPOSIT ADD     345678901 (VALUE)(P75) NNNN    VALUEVARIABLE
```

These are tab delimited text files. There are total of 5 columns in each file. (123456789 (VALUE)(VARIABLE) is a single value column).

My requirements are:

1. I need to fetch only the row which contains P75 to update in the
   same file.
2. I have to replace the values in Col3,Col4 and in Col5 after fetching
   P75 other rows should be unaffected.
3. I have to update multiple files with same configuration in the same folder.
4. Only the records which contains P75 should be updated like this. The
   replace values are same for all selected records.
5. After replace I have to copy these to location 1 and move these
   files to location2

My script's try command is as follows.

```
$CurrFilePath : C:\testing
$TransIncludePattern =b*.txt

try 
{    #Get-ChildItem -Path $CurrFilePath\* -Include $TransIncludePattern | sort LastWriteTime | Select-Object -First 1 | ForEach-Object  { 
     $CurrFileName = Get-childitem -Path $CurrFilePath\* -Include $TransIncludePattern | sort LastWriteTime 
     $CurrFileName |
     select -ExpandProperty fullname |
        foreach {
        (Get-Content $_) |
          ForEach-Object {If($_ -match '\(VALUE\)\(P75\)'){$_ -replace '\(VALUE\)\(P75\)','(VTG)(SPVTG)' -replace 'VALUEVARIABLE', 'VTGSPVTG' -replace 'NNNN', 'TCM'} else {$_} | Set-Content $_
          Write-Host "File Changed : " $_
        }   
        }
         Write-Host "P75 values are now replaced"

        Copy-Item $CurrFileName -Destination $OutFilePath  -force   
        Move-Item -CurrFileName $file -Destination $ProcessFilePath  
      
     
    Write-Host "Total Elapsed Time: $($elapsed.Elapsed.ToString())"  

    EXIT 0
      
}
```

I am getting error as :

```
+ ...  -replace 'NNNN', 'TCM'} else {$_} | Set-Con ...
+                                                                 ~
An empty pipe element is not allowed.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement
```

How can I get my requirements fulfilled without this error popping up?

Please advice.

Thanks

Comment: you have a long catch. Are you sure it always delivers something ? Probably good to format your code more readable and and use some debugging /Write-Output

Comment: I have already answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63285579/9898643)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your code is poorly formatted and not readable. Use indents, proper logging (Write-Host or Write-Output) and line breaks.
Proper code debugging starts with reading a code you've just created :)
Paths and patterns are safer when contained in a quotes.

For the code itself - no need to check if line matches the regex. If it does -replace changes the value and if it doesn't - lane stays as it was.
You made a double foreach there, so there was an empty pipe introduced.

```
$CurrFilePath = "C:\SomePath"
$TransIncludePattern = "b*.txt"
try {    
    #Get-ChildItem -Path $CurrFilePath\* -Include $TransIncludePattern | sort LastWriteTime | Select-Object -First 1 | ForEach-Object  { 
    $CurrFileName = Get-childitem -Path $CurrFilePath\* -Include $TransIncludePattern | Sort-Object LastWriteTime;
    $CurrFileName | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | 
        ForEach-Object {
            Write-Host "Changing file $_";
            $content = (Get-Content $_);
            $newContent = $content | ForEach-Object {
                ((($_ -replace '\(VALUE\)\(P75\)','(VTG)(SPVTG)') -replace 'VALUEVARIABLE', 'VTGSPVTG') -replace 'NNNN', 'TCM');
            }
            $newContent | Set-Content $_; #or [IO.File]::WriteAllLines($_, $newContent) :)

            Write-Host "File Changed: $_";
        }
    Write-Host "P75 values are now replaced";

    Copy-Item $CurrFileName -Destination $OutFilePath -Force;
    Move-Item -CurrFileName $file -Destination $ProcessFilePath;
      
     
    Write-Host "Total Elapsed Time: $($elapsed.Elapsed.ToString())";

    exit 0;
}
catch {
    Write-Error $_;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This is working. However, all the rows are getting updated. I need to update the row which contains "(P75)" Initially I have the "if" statement in the question. Can you help me add the condition so that it fetches only P75 records.

Comment: SOLVED: Used If else statement inside the replace loop. Thanks @Grzegorz :)